# Can’t figure out how to make the route work

Tags: kong

I am using Kong (open source) 3.4.0 running as docker container with database. I have a backend (NodeJS) which has one entry point as “/”

I have created a service with a route that has a path as “/v1” with strip path and preserve host.
This route uses a auth plugin which requires apikey in the header.
So anything that gets called from the client (“/v1/user”) needs to be authenticated(apikey) and then the backend matches with “/user” route. This works perfectly.

I have another route on the backend with “/help” and I want this route to not be authenticated(does not require apikey in the header).
So when a client calls (“/v1/help”) this would match the route in the backend and a response will be returned. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you edit your question and provide some code for under standing ?

Comment: as you are controlling the API route to parent level based on the question and not at the specific API route level, seems like a difficult option. If you have different approaches for same route then I believe going to that level will solve your problem.

Comment: @Shaleen for a temporary solution I had created a new service to handle the unauthorized route. This will be horrible to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by defining the routes in the service.

You can define two services in Kong pointing to same NodeJS service in backend

1. **nodejs-auth:** requires auth (key-auth) plugin
2. **nodejs-no-auth:** doesn't require auth

Add the route `/v1/user` in **nodejs-auth** service & route `/v1/help` in **nodejs-no-auth** service.

Comment: I know I am coming on to this after a long time. I was following your solution for a single route but now say I want to add /v1/help1 or more, should I create more routes or is there a better way to do it altogether in single service